# How does iOS app get messages from JMS queue

Tags: java, ios, api

I have a mobile app with a backend that will connect to a JMS server. The user of the app will make a search, this search will then be sent through the JMS API to our data provider. The results then need to be sent back to the app. How does the mobile app interface with the JMS API? If it makes any difference, the JMS API must be hosted by Solace, no other platforms like Glassfish are available per requirements of our data provider.

Comment: You'll need to generate a Push Notification from your server (to Apples Push Notification Service (APNs)). The App will need to be configured to be able to receive these notifications

Comment: the data will be used to populate a table inside the app. Can notifications do this?

Comment: Well, it's JSON based, with a limit of up to 2kb (this might have changed) - see [Creating the Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) for more details

Comment: Do you know how the app would go about sending a message to the JMS queue? I'm wondering if using a REST API as a middle man might be the way to go? Also I dont think 2kb of data would allow enough characters. each request will populate approx 50-100 cells in the app. Each cell containing 4-6 labels of data.

Comment: You limited by what Apple allows you to do. You could send batches of data but the order and timeliness of the deliver is up in the air. Communicating with APNs is a little complicated as you'll need to generate a token/certificate and communicate to the service with that - how exactly I don't know, I've only ever done it as an experiment using a simple client based tool - as far as I know, it's just a type of web service backed by JSON

Comment: You could further look at [Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) or you could [google for a Java implementation](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&q=java+apns&oq=java+apns&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.0.0.0.3881.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.VASfASqbC8Q) - just remember, you need to the http based implementation